# how to lunch Dart dev tool via vs code

Tags: flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code, inspector

I can't find the Dart Dev tool in vs code when I press the open devtool. -> open dev tool in browser -< it shows flutter dev tool insteed.
I'm looking for this->[image]

in steed I got this:[image]

Comment: what's the problem with the web dev tools

Comment: Just an aside... I have a small monitor, so I have devtools launch in an external chrome window so it doesn't get in the way of my code fixing while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to select the Widget Details tree tab

[image]

Comment: it doesn't show the Dart dev Tool as I mentioned in Picture 1. and I don't have some tools like Rainbow and debug banner...as well as the top toolbar

Comment: The picture 1 that you provide is the old interface of your picture 2.